# Как совместить функционал вкладок и карусели в bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Есть неадаптивная совмещенная карусель с табами, которая переключает контент, как по вкладкам, так и по стрелкам, но у этого решения проблема с адаптивом, поэтому интересует как можно его внедрить в структуру сетки `bootsrap`? [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/cmaxm854/1/)

```js
var CAROUSEL = {
  id: 0,
  width: 500,
  length: 0,
  ready: function() {

    var self = jQuery('#panels');
    var plane = self.find('.panels-ul');

    CAROUSEL.length = plane.find('.panels-li').length;

    plane.width(CAROUSEL.length * (CAROUSEL.width + 10) + 100);

    $('#tabs .tab:first').show();

    $('#types-menu .group a').click(function(e) {
      var index = $('#types-menu .group a').index(this);
      plane.animate({
        'left': -(CAROUSEL.width * index)
      }, 'slow');
      CAROUSEL.id = index;
      CAROUSEL.resetDisable();
      return false;
    });

    self.find('.arrow.arg').click(function() {

      if (CAROUSEL.id < 6) {
        plane.animate({
          'left': '-=' + CAROUSEL.width + 'px'
        }, 'slow');
        CAROUSEL.id++;
        CAROUSEL.resetDisable();
      }

      return false;
    });

    self.find('.arrow.alf').click(function() {

      if (CAROUSEL.id > 0) {
        plane.animate({
          'left': '+=' + CAROUSEL.width + 'px'
        }, 'slow');
        CAROUSEL.id--;
        CAROUSEL.resetDisable();
      }

      return false;
    });

    CAROUSEL.resetDisable();
  },
  resetDisable: function() {
    $('.arrow.alf, .arrow.arg').removeClass('disable');

    $('#tabs .tab').hide().eq(CAROUSEL.id).show();

    $('.backline span font').text($('#types-menu .group a').eq(CAROUSEL.id).text());

    if (CAROUSEL.id == 0)
      $('.arrow.alf').addClass('disable');
    else if (CAROUSEL.id == 6)
      $('.arrow.arg').addClass('disable');

    $('#types-menu .group a').removeClass('active').eq(CAROUSEL.id).addClass('active');
  }
};

$(function() {

  CAROUSEL.ready();

});
```

```css
#types .desc {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#types .desc .image {
  float: left;
}
#types .desc span {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 129px;
  padding: 14px 0 0 0;
}
#types .desc h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#panels {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#panels .panels {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#panels .panels .panels-ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#panels .panels .panels-ul .panels-li {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
}
#panels .panels .panels-ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#panels .panels .panels-ul .panels-li li:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}
#panels .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 30px;
}
#panels .arrow.alf {
  background: url(http://www.muenzmanufaktur.com/images/main/sl_prev.png) no-repeat;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  left: -60px;
}
#panels .arrow.arg {
  background: url(http://www.muenzmanufaktur.com/images/main/sl_next.png) no-repeat;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
  right: -60px;
}
#panels .arrow.alf.disable {
  background-position: left top;
}
#panels .arrow.arg.disable {
  background-position: right top;
}
#types h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#types-menu {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#types-menu .group {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
#types-menu .group li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
#types-menu .group li a {
  color: #20478d;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #20478d;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#types-menu .group li a:hover {
  color: #28262d;
  border-bottom: none;
}
#types-menu .group li a.active {
  color: #28262d;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="types">
  <div id="types-menu">
    <ul class="group">
      <li><a href="index.html#" class="active">1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html#">2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html#">3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html#">4</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html#">5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="panels">
    <div class="panels">
      <ul class="panels-ul">
        <div class="panels-li">
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="panels-li">
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="panels-li">
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="panels-li">
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="panels-li">
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
          <li>
            <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow alf disable"></div>
    <div class="arrow arg"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs">
    <div class="desc tab">
      <span><h3>название 1</h3>текст</span>
    </div>
    <div class="desc tab">
      <span><h3>название 2</h3>текст</span>
    </div>
    <div class="desc tab">
      <span><h3>название 3</h3>текст</span>
    </div>
    <div class="desc tab">
      <span><h3>название 4</h3>текст</span>
    </div>
    <div class="desc tab">
      <span><h3>название 5</h3>текст</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь почему то ошибку выдает, но [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsg54995/) работает. Если это то что нужно и что то не понятно, то готов ответить на ваши вопросы.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var tabs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector(".nav").children, 0);
  
  $('.glyphicon').on('click', function(e) {

    var event = jQuery.Event('click');
    
    tabs.forEach(function(item) {

      if ( $(item).hasClass('active') ) {
       
        var id = parseInt( item.getAttribute('data-slide-to') );
        
        if ( $(e.target).hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-left') ) {
          if (id == 0) {
            id = tabs.length-1;
          } else {
            id -= 1;        
          }
        }
        
        if ( $(e.target).hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-right') ) {
          if (id == tabs.length-1) {
            id = 0;
          } else {
            id += 1;
          }
        }

       var elem = '.js-link-' + id;

       jQuery(elem).trigger(event);
        
      }
      
    });
    
  });

});
```

```css
.item {
  background: lightblue;
}

.carousel {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  top: -40px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.carousel-indicators li a {
  width: 38px;
}

.carousel-control {
  width: 0%;
}

.glyphicon {
  color: grey;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  margin-left: 10px;
  top: 20px;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  margin-right: 10px;
  top: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
    margin-left: 10px;
    top: 50%;
  }
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    margin-right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
        <a data-toggle="pill" class="js-link js-link-0" href="#1">1</a>
      </li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
        <a data-toggle="pill" class="js-link js-link-1" href="#2">2</a>
      </li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
        <a data-toggle="pill" class="js-link js-link-2" href="#3">3</a>
      </li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chania</h3>
          <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Flowers</h3>
          <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tab-content">

    <div id="1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Some content in menu 3.</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо за попытку разобраться, я немного подправил ваше решение под свой вариант https://jsfiddle.net/cmaxm854/1/ получилось вот так https://jsfiddle.net/tsg54995/1/ но у меня меня остался вопрос почему в моем случае смена слайдов плавная, а вашем - какая-то дерганая? давайте вместе доведем эту задачку до конца и я отмечу ответ, как правильный

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "дерганная"? Вроде такая же как у вас анимация смены слайда т.е. стандартная бутстраповская, в смену слайдов никаких изменений не вносил.

Comment: я имею ввиду при смене слайда надписи в описании подергиваются с затуханием здесь https://jsfiddle.net/tsg54995/1/
чего не наблюдается тут https://jsfiddle.net/cmaxm854/1/

Comment: Это было из-за стандартного класса анимации табов `.fade` в `.tab-content` здесь убрал его https://jsfiddle.net/tsg54995/2/ Если вам не нужен текст в карусели, то лучше удалить `.carousel-caption` с его содержимым.

Comment: да, отлично! Спасибо)